# I can't submit my form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.6

i want to make Multi Step Form so i create a class form, and a function in the controller, my problem is i can't submit my form

i try all is thing :

- $formTransfertFonds->isValid()
- $formTransfertFonds->isSubmitted()
- $this->get('request')->isMethod('post')

---

```
    public function indexTransfertFondsCcpAction()
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $transfertFonds = new TransfertFonds();
        $step = 1;
        $formTransfertFonds = $this->createForm(new TransfertFondsType($step), $transfertFonds );
        $formTransfertFonds->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formTransfertFonds->isSubmitted())
        if ( $this->get('request')->isMethod('post') ) {
            echo "ok"; }
        }

        return $this->render('@EgovPoste/Ccp/indexTransfertFondsAccountCcp.html.twig',
            array('formTransfertFonds' => $formTransfertFonds->createView(),
                  'step' => $step
            )
        );
    }
```

i create a variable $step for pass it to my form

```
class TransfertFondsType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $step;
    public function __construct($step) {$this->step = $step;}
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        switch ($this->step) {
            case 1:
                $builder
                    ->add('toNumCompte')
                    ->add('montant', 'money')
                    ->add('Suivant', 'submit')
                    ->getForm();

                break;
            case 2:
                $builder
                    ->add(
                        'typeTransfert',
                        'choice',
                        array(
                            'choices' => array(
                                'maintenant' => 'Juste maintenant',
                                'unique' => 'Unique',
                                'permanent' => 'Permanent',
                            ),
                            'expanded' => true,
                            'multiple' => false,
                        )
                    )
                    ->add(
                        'optionEmail',
                        'checkbox',
                        array(
                            'label' => 'Recevoir une copie par e-mail de ma confirmation de virement',
                            'data' => false,
                            'required' => false,
                        )
                    )
                    ->add('Retour', 'submit')
                    ->add('Suivant', 'submit');
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Egov\CoreBundle\Entity\TransfertFonds',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName() { return 'TransfertFondsType';}
}
```

Comment: What does "i can't submit my form" mean? What happened? What did you expect instead? Did you get any errors?

Comment: nothing to happened,and when i click inspect element and click submit button it add me a `<div class="ajax-error">Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0</div>`

Comment: So how do you actually submit the form? Is there some JavaScript involved doing AJAX requests or the like?

Comment: usually the same problem, i'am using a template with a lot of js file but in my layout when i delete this line  `<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('bundles/egovclient/js/jquery.form.min.js') }}"></script>
` the form work fine but a large part of my work don"t work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
if ($formTransfertFonds->isSubmitted() && $formTransfertFonds->isValid()) {
        //Do what you want
    }
```

To pass you variable in form use :

```
$this->createForm(new TransfertFondsType($step), $transfertFonds, array('attr' => array('step' => $step );
```

And use it with :

`$options['attr']['step']`